# Function-argument a:var not recognized as variable?

Tags: vimscript

I'm struggling with strange case. I've read many help pages and search through net but found nothing.

In my vimrc:

```
function! s:rename(name)
    try
        echom a:name
        saveas a:name
        " bd #
        " silent !rm #
    endtry
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 Ren call s:rename(<f-args>)
```

In a file:

```
:Ren newname
:messages
```

> newname
>   "a:name" 4L, 9C written

Why `a:name` is not recognized as a variable!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:saveas` expects a filename as an argument (see `:h :saveas`).

So, inside your function, when you pass `a:name` to `:saveas`, it treats it as a filename.
If you want to pass the contents of the variable `a:name`, you can write this:

```
execute 'saveas ' . a:name
```

The difference is that `:execute` expects an expression (see `:h :execute`).
`'saveas '` is a string, which is a type of expression.
`a:name` is a variable, which here is replaced with its contents.
It's the same kind of evaluation you see when you type:

```
:let myvar = 'hello'
:echo myvar
```

`myvar` is automatically evaluated into its value after `:echo`, just like after `:execute`, but not after `:saveas`. Because, again, the first 2 commands expect expressions as arguments, whereas the latter expects a filename.

The evaluation of `a:name` is a string which contains your filename, and the dot between `saveas` and `a:name` is the concatenation operator (see `:h expr-.`). The result of the concatenation is again a string which is still a kind of expression.

So, `:execute` receives an expression as an argument, which is what it expects, and executes it as an Ex command.